# Undefined response with Mongo

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this schema (Cart) and this can have an array of products, and the product have two important fields for this case, one is **_id** and the other is **sellPrice**.

```
let cartSchema = new Schema({
    ...
    products: [{
        _id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Product',
            required: [true, '{PATH} required']
        },
        cant: {
            type: Number,
            required: [true, '{PATH} required'],
            default: 1
        },
        sellPrice: {
            type: Number
        }
    }],
    ...
});
```

When I want to add a Cart to the DB, I use this function:

```
let addCart = (req, res) => {
    let body = req.body;
    let cart = new Cart({
        ...
        products: body.products,
        ...
    });
    cart.products.forEach(product => {
        let id = product._id;
        let productObt = Product.findById(id)
        .exec((err, productDB) => {
            if (err) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!productDB) {
                return false;
            }
            console.log(productDB);
            product.sellPrice = productDB.sellPrice;
            return productDB;
        });
        console.log(productObt);
    });
    console.log(cart); // this cart is wrong, this show: 
    //products: [
    //    { cant: 1, _id: 5fa00779e8c8633bd00dc9c5 },
    //    { cant: 1, _id: 5fa006dde8c8633bd00dc9c0 }
    //],
    //without sellPrice
    cart.save((err, cartDB) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                error: err
            })
        }
        res.json({
            ok: true,
            cart: cartDB._id
        })
    });
}
```

What I'm trying to do on the forEach, is for every product in the array, get his sellPrice on that moment in the document in the DB so I can add this price to the `cart.products[].sellPrice` and save this to the DB. But the `console.log(productObt);` returns null and the `console.log(productDB);` don't.

I think is because `.exec` is asynchronous and I need to use better the callback but I'm a little new on NodeJS and JS so I don't know how to return the info in productDB. Any suggestion? Ty.

Comment: The answer is that you don't return it. Do whatever you need to do with that value inside the exec callback.

Comment: I want to add to `product.sellPrice` the value of the `productDB.sellPrice` so I can save this value in the Cart schema of the DB.

Comment: Yes. Do that inside the exec callback.

Comment: I edit the question so I can show better what I tried.
I tried to do this next to ` console.log(productDB);` I added `product.sellPrice = productDB.sellPrice`. But after the forEach, I use `console.log(cart)`and the sellPrice don't show in the products.